# The program does not print the data correctly

Tags: c

Hello I have a program that accepts some parameters and prints things according, The problem The program prints all the parameters instead of those that need to be printed. I would be happy if you could tell me what my mistake and how do I fix it thanks.

Code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int i;

for(i = 0; i < argc ; i++)
{
    if("/n")
    {
        printf("My name is pop\n");
        break;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < argc ; i++)
{
    if("/b")
    {
        printf("My birthday is 7.1.1999\n");
        break;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < argc ; i++)
{
    if("/f")
    {
        printf("My favorite food is pizza\n");
        break;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < argc ; i++)
{
    if("/?")
    {
        printf("/n = print name\n/b = print Birthday\n/f = Favorite Food\n");
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This almost looks like an attempt to use Perl idioms in C, a string literal like `"/n"` will decay to a pointer which will evaluate to true.

Comment: The tests like `if ("/n")` are doubly misguided.  If you're looking for a newline, that is spelled `"\n"` with a backslash, not a slash.  A character string constant never has a zero address, so the condition is always true, so the code in the 'then' block is always executed.  You're probably looking for something like `if (strcmp(argv[i], "/n") == 0)` if you expect the user to run: `yourprog /n`, which is a Windows-ish way of writing command line options.

Answer (score 1):

Horrible mis-use of the C syntax. "It's so bad, it's not even wrong."

```
if("/n")
```

A constant string used this way, checks if the 'result' evaluates to 0. It tests the address of your constant string, and hey! it's not 0! So the code inside the braces gets executed.

Look in your favourite reference how to compare strings.

Also, you might want to skip `arg[0]`, because it (usually) is the name of your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
if("/b")
    {
        printf("My birthday is 7.1.1999\n");
        break;
    }
```

Anything non-zero in C is true. `"/b"` and other values are non-zero. So, your `if` condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `strcmp`.

```
if(strcmp(argv[i], "/b") == 0)
    printf("My name is pop\n");
```

**Edit**

```
for(i = 0; i < argc ; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(argv[i], "/n") == 0)
    {
        printf("My name is pop\n");
        continue;
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[i], "/b") == 0)
    {
        printf("My birthday is 7.1.1999\n");
        continue;
    }

    //...etc
}
```

Even with this your approach is unconventional.  Typically you would want to employ something like `getopts` which will parse the command line for you.

Comment: Yes, the remainder is called programming.  Your entire loop is wrong.  You only need to loop through the arguments once and have all the comparisons within that loop.